# SQL sum multiple columns by multiple id

Tags: sql, sum, firebird

I'd like to sum a table by multiple columns and ids.

My table (which is the join of 2 tables) looks like this:

```
unique_ID, year, ID1, Amount1, ID2, Amount2, ID3, Amount3, ... , ID6, Amount6;
```

I need to get the sum of amounts `(Amount1+Amount2+...+Amount6)` where IDs match `(ID1=ID2=...=ID6)`.

So the result table would look like this:
`Year, ID1(/ID2/.../ID6), Amount1 + ... + Amount6`

**Example data: (made with excel)**

```
Source table                                    
UID     YEAR    ROOM1       AMOUNT1 ROOM2       AMOUNT2
15823   2015    Material1   1       Material3   8
15298   2015    Material1   2       Material3   9
22405   2015    Material2   3       Material4   10
22403   2015    Material2   4       Material5   11
22404   2015    Material2   5       Material5   12
25417   2016    Material1   6                   0
31435   2016    Material2   7       Material2   13

Result table        
YEAR    Material    AMOUNT
2015    Material1   3
2015    Material2   12
2015    Material3   17
2015    Material4   10
2015    Material5   23
2016    Material1   6
2016    Material2   20
```

**Explanation:**
I have a large table with products, where every product can contain maximum 6 raw material. (ID 1-6 identifies material, Amount 1-6 shows the amount of used material). The order of materials can vary.
I need to know the amount of used materials by year and by materials.

I have half-solutions which need a lot of afterwork in excel.
Is there any simple and elegant solution to do it in SQL?

I am using Firebird, but any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This looks like bad table design.  Why are the amounts in different columns?

Comment: Please post some sample data and output you expect for the same.

Comment: It is designed this way. Every record (row) is a product, with maximum 6 rooms for raw materials.

Comment: I don't understand the desired result table, yet. You have a table of products. Each product consists of up to six materials. There are probably many materials to choose from, let's say 30 different materials, each identified by its ID (that you reference in ID1 to ID6). Now you want to know the total amount per material ID and year? Then I'd expect a result of three columns: year, ID, total. Is this what you want?

Comment: @KeyurPanchal edited some sample data to original post

Comment: @ThorstenKettner Yes, I think you see the situation right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want the total amount per year and material. So first get a proper material/year table on-the-fly, then aggregate:

```
select 
  year,
  material_id,
  sum(amount) as total
from
(
  select year, id1 as material_id, amount1 as amount from mytable
  union all
  select year, id2 as material_id, amount2 as amount from mytable
  union all
  select year, id3 as material_id, amount3 as amount from mytable
  union all
  select year, id4 as material_id, amount4 as amount from mytable
  union all
  select year, id5 as material_id, amount5 as amount from mytable
  union all
  select year, id6 as material_id, amount6 as amount from mytable
) materials
where material_id is not null
group by year, material_id
order by year, material_id;
```

Comment: One more question. "mytable" is a join of 2 other tables. Now I have to make it in every step. How can I make it only once, before the the main select and then just refer to it?

Comment: @JánosiZoltánJános edit your question and show in the question those two tables as they are. Also, this design seems very questionable. Different materials should be different rows not different columns.

Comment: @Arioch'The I think, becouse my original question is answered (and solved), I close this one, and post a new one. Thank you all for the help!